# Multi line regex expression

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following file, and I'm trying to use `/\|\".*\"\|/gm` match `multi line..end here`, but the regex finds nothing using `sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\|\".*\"\|/abcxyz/gm' t >  t.2`, I can't find out what's wrong with it.

```
    |2012-10-12 13:41:08.067|2012-10-12 13:45:03.282|f||"multi line star t herer erj
jdkajdkfj 
   end here"|2017
```

Comment: Is it a perl or a sed question?

Comment: It's a sed question

Comment: I don't know about sed, but with Perl, use `/s` instead of `/gm` and it should match.

Comment: sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\|\".*\"\|/abcxyz/gm' t >  t.2

Comment: The _multiline_ modifier is inappropriate here. It would be used in conjunction with ^ or $ both, symbolizing the _beginning_ or _end_ of the line. Only if used in the regex will there be any meaning. Don't know about sed, but the dot `.` metachar will match everything except newline. So `.*` will not span newlines, thus your regex will only match if the literals are found on a single line. Normally the dot will match newline as well with the  _Dot-All_ modifier, which is usually `(?s)` inline or `/.../s` within a regex delimiter syntax.

Comment: Just a thought that may be helpful, if I have multi lines to search I'll first regex out all the \n and then parse it.  If I need to put it back I'll sub.regex all the \n with this_is_a_holder_for_the_return or some string, get my matches, then put it back.  Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from [the GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt):

> The 'M' modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU 'sed'
>        extension which directs GNU 'sed' to match the regular expression
>        in 'multi-line' mode.  The modifier causes '^' and '$' to match
>        respectively (in addition to the normal behavior) the empty string
>        after a newline, and the empty string before a newline.  There are
>        special character sequences ('`' and '\'') which always match the
>        beginning or the end of the buffer.  In addition, **the period
>        character does not match a new-line character in multi-line mode.**

(emphasis added)

You need to add `\n` to match the (possibly multiple?) newlines explicitly, or else do it a different way. I'd suggest using `[^\"]` in place of `.*`, unless you know there's only one quoted field per record in the file.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, **that is all**. If you are using sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you are using functionality that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='multi line.*end here' 'RT{print RT}' file
multi line star t herer erj
jdkajdkfj
end here
```

If that's not what you're looking for then edit your question to clarify the expected output and your requirements for matching it (string vs regexp, case sensitive vs insensitive, partial vs full, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/|".*"|/|"abcxyz"|/' file
```

The `|` and the `"` do not need to be quoted. If the `|` is quoted it acts as the alternation metacharacter i.e. `this|that` meaning this or that.

N.B. The `:a;N;$!ba` construct slurps the entire file into memory and because the `.*` is greedy, more than one record may be matched.